# 16.04 LTSP Thick Clients Need USB Headset Support?

Tags: usb, sound, ltsp

I am in a bit of a bind and Google has been no help. We run a call center with 80 stations, which all PXE boot a Ubuntu 16.04 LTSP desktop from a central server using the [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/) project code. We recently got a new contract with a client requiring the client's VOIP software. This means the stations need a USB headset connected to pass the call audio back and forth.

For the life of me, I cannot get the thick client to see the headset. I have tried a few things from Google, i.e. removing and reinstalling [alsa](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Pulse Audio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/), but that has not worked.

My Linux skill is mediocre at best, i.e. I can run apt-get and the like, but can't really delve deep "under the hood" after that. I know enough to get the server to work with what we needed it for, until now.

Any advice that could be given would be great!

***EDIT:

The thick clients are a mix of Dell and HP desktop PCs bought from Amazon. All of them vary by specs and they are all refurb/off-lease machines.

The headsets are Wantek A600 plug and play headsets***

Comment: "USB headset" sounds a bit vague. Do you see this device in `lsusb`? Do you see the device in `pavucontrol` or `paman`? Do you have any clues that it is linux-compatible? LTSP here is not the problem, you can install all needed software to image whenever you would understand which software to install.

Comment: What are your 'thick' clients? Please click [edit] and add their make and model numbers (please get the latter from the serial number plate). Please don't use Add comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: @Bcarson76, thanks for edit, but please do not forget adding output of `lsusb` with headset connected. Screeshots of `pavucontrol` and `paman` maybe useful too.